# ALT + CTRL shortcuts in MATE problem

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-shortcuts, mate-desktop

I've installed MATE under Arch Linux. I've a problem with the shortcuts.

A lot of the shortcuts doesn't work so I tried to change them.

When I'm trying to reassign the shortcut I go to Settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts, clicking the row I want to change and pressing the shortcut.

The problem is, when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> then <kbd>ALT</kbd> then <kbd>L</kbd> the command becomes:
<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

If I change the order the buttons i press down the keys to <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> the result is:
<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

So it looks like MATE only takes one of <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd>, the first one down, and not both of them as I want.

Does anyone have an idea why this could be?

It's not a new installation of Arch, but it is a new installation of MATE and Xorg.

Comment: Hmm. I just tested this under my installation of arch and mate (fully -Syu'd as of yesterday) and it works for me. Did you try both (right and left) of your CTRL/ALT keys? Could it be a keyboard failure?

Comment: Hi, It's the same if I using the right CTRL. I just tested installing GNOME 3 and there it worked, so it looks like there is a setting or other software issue in MATE. I Syu'd my Arch before installing MATE so it should be up to date.

Comment: Dunno then, but that's my two cents :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found it.

I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> to switch keyboard layouts. If I change that to something else, then all of the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> shortcuts work as they should.

Must be a bug then.

Comment: Ah, like ibus or another input method editor? I typically use Super+Space, which is why I never ran into this issue.